# How can I indent the wrapped text in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, autoindent

How can I change Notepad++ setting so that wrapped lines gets indented automatically?

Right now I have something like this:

```
some text that wraps to
next line
    some indented text 
that also wraps
```

What I want to get is:

```
some text that wraps to
next line
    some indented text 
    that also wraps
```

Comment: I just wanted to do exactly opposite. So **Line Wrap** option to _default_ worked well for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In **Settings → Preferences... → Editing** set the **Line Wrap** option to *Indent*.

Comment: This worked. I was using older version, so did not have the setting available.

Comment: Strange, I have to use the `Line Wrap` setting `Aligned` to get what is shown in the original question. If I use `Indent`, the wrapped line is indented 1 step further (to indicate that it is a wrapped line, I assume)

Comment: For this to work, remember to enable Word wrap from the menu: `View->Word wrap`

Comment: The amount of indentation may be further customized: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Managing_Line_Lengths

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable auto indentation in Notepad++:

Settings → Preferences → Misc. → check "Auto-indent".

You can also click the "Show Indent Guide" button for better view.

Comment: That will auto-indent *new* lines, but it will **not** indent *wrapped* lines.