# How to have vim left-align indented lines (like is possible in Notepad++)

Tags: vim, notepad++, indentation

In Notepad++ there is a linewrap option that can be set to `aligned` so that indented, wrapped lines align at the same left margin. See also here: [How can I indent the wrapped text in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/484578/how-can-i-indent-the-wrapped-text-in-notepad).

Is there a setting to get the same behaviour in VIM?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828174/word-wrap-in-vim-preserving-indentation

Answer (score 0):

This line indents wrapped content by 4 spaces:

```
set showbreak=\ \ \ \ <- there's a <Space> here
```

See `:help 'showbreak'`.

The *breakindent* patch in EBGreen's comment is smarter.

Comment: Yes, I noticed the `showbreak` option in EBGreen's comment. However, it is indeed not very smart, as it only works correctly for a single indent.

Comment: Indeed. The breakindent patch is the way to go.